# Photoshop CC Javascript - Flip Layer / Image

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I need to be able to flip an image / active layer either vertically or horizontally.

Looking throughout the [Adobe Photoshop CC Javascript Reference](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref.pdf) there doesn't appear to be a flip method for the activelayer/object.

```
doc.flipCanvas(Direction.VERTICAL)
```

Does work but that obviously flips the entire document vertically where as I want to do it on just the active layer

I can see in the `invert()` method it does mention:

> inverts the selection (deselects the selection and selects the rest of
>   the layer or document). Tip. To flip the selection shape, see **rotate**

And that says the following:

> rotate (angle [, anchor]) -
>
> Rotates the selection by the specified amount around the specified anchor

I'm already using the rotate method like so elsewhere and cannot see how I can flip the image through this?

```
obj.rotate( rotation,  AnchorPosition.TOPLEFT );
```

Comment: Interesting question! I don't see a way to transform a flip. I hope someone else has a better answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no flip method for ArtLayer, you can use `.resize` instead:

> Resizes the layer to the specified
>   dimensions (as a percentage of
>   its current size) and places it in
>   the specified position.

```
activeDocument.activeLayer.resize(-100,undefined); //will flip layer horizontally
activeDocument.activeLayer.resize(undefined,-100); //will flip layer vertically
```

(there's also a third argument for an anchor point)

Answer (score 0):

```
var idFlip = charIDToTypeID( "Flip" );
var desc16024 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
var ref2273 = new ActionReference();
var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
ref2273.putEnumerated( idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt );
desc16024.putReference( idnull, ref2273 );
var idAxis = charIDToTypeID( "Axis" );
var idOrnt = charIDToTypeID( "Ornt" );
var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
desc16024.putEnumerated( idAxis, idOrnt, idHrzn );
executeAction( idFlip, desc16024, DialogModes.NO );
```

Will flip a layer horizontally.